# Using CSS grid, position multi-row children directly under each other

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css grid layout like the below. It has a main content section and 2 sidebar sections that are in separate containers.

The reason for this is because for narrow viewports I want the first sidebar section to appear above the main content, and the second sidebar to be at the bottom.

I've been trying to achieve this by using multiple grid rows and positioning the child sections using the `grid-row` and `grid-column` css properties.

For narrow viewports I can use the `order` property to move the first sidebar section to the top.

I'm close to getting where I need to be, but there's a problem when the main content is taller than the first sidebar content. The grid system is starting the second row at the midpoint of the total height of the grid container. Ideally the second row would start at the bottom of the first sidebar item so the second sidebar item will render just underneath.

How can I get the second sidebar item to position itself there?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
  background: lavender;
}

.main-content {
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
}

.main-content>div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: salmon;

}

.aside-1 {

  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}

.aside-1>div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: teal;
}

.aside-2 {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: gold;
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div>This is the main content
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside class="aside-1">
    <div>This is the first sidebar content</div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="aside-2">
    <div>This is the second sidebar content. I want it to be just under the first. but instead there's a large gap.</div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to completely stretch the `aside`? Then you can use `height:100%` which will take all the height.

Comment: And why not use a media query?

Comment: No, I want the height of each item to be automatic according to its content

Comment: @Paulie_D For the purpose of this question I'm only asking about positioning in the 2-column layout. I only mentioned the narrow viewport to explain why I've marked it up the way I have. I will of course use media queries to acheive the responsive layout

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS-Grid can't do that, that's not the way it works. You'd need to wrap the asides in a separate container and perhaps use `display:contents` when needed to re-arrange as required.

Comment: OK, yeah, I figured an alternative is to render `aside-1` twice; once in each location, and only display one depending on viewport

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Wrapping the asides and using `display:contents` to *unwrap* in a media query would be much better.

Comment: Ah, yes, `display:contents` is probably what I'm after. I did not know that existed

Answer (score 1):

make 3 rows instead of 2

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  background: lavender;
}

.main-content {
  grid-row: span 3; /* here you make it 3 */
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.main-content>div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: salmon;
}

.aside-1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.aside-1>div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: teal;
}

.aside-2 {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: gold;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div>This is the main content
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside class="aside-1">
    <div>This is the first sidebar content</div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="aside-2">
    <div>This is the second sidebar content. I want it to be just under the first. but instead there's a large gap.</div>
  </aside>
</div>
```